# What's the difference between "if she should win the race" and "if she wins the race"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I would like to know the difference  between

> If she should win the race, congratulate her.

and

> If she wins the race, congratulate her.

I would like to know if there is a difference in the meaning or if one is more formal than the other.

Answer (score 2):

Both of them refer to a possible event that could happen in the future. However, there is difference in nuance. The former indicates the speaker thinks the possibility of the event happening is low. However, the latter is neutral.

"If she should win the race" could be rephrased to:

> I don't think she is likely to win the race, but if she happens to win
>   the race...

"If it should rain tomorrow" could be rephrased to:

> I don't think it will rain tomorrow (based on experience looking at
>   the sky, according to weather forecast, etc.), but if it happens to
>   rain tomorrow.

The former could be more formal than the latter.

Comment: You say that "should... indicates that the speaker thinks the possibility of the event happening is low": I think that it is neutral. None of the dictionaries I have checked indicate any bias, and the Cambridge dictionary proposes it as a replacement for "if".

Comment: @JavaLatte I have searched for another opinion and found [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199723/if-should-or-if-present-simple-or-too-many-ways-to-say-the-same-thing) that happens to have the same view.

Comment: @JavaLatte they don't have the same meaning. It's not exactly a replacement. In other cases might be a replacement without any change of meaning, but here there is a slight change in meaning as this answer says.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is the same, and the **should** version is formal. The version without **should** is considerably more common.

[should](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/should) modal verb (POSSIBILITY) › formal used when referring to a ​possible ​event in the ​future:

> If anyone should ​ask for me, I'll be in the manager's ​office.
>
> Should you (= if you) ​ever need anything, ​please don't ​hesitate to ​contact me.

Comment: Both answers are good I don't know which one to select as answer I think I'll wait for people to vote.

Comment: @ManuelHernandez Java, they don't mean the same thing. There is a subtle difference.